# PHP process and render page faster

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a system using PHP & mysql, where I have a member profile page which has got so many things to display on page like connections, photos, recent activities, connection activities, full profile including personal info, education details work experience and many more. I would like to know how should i process this page using PHP. what technique should I use to process all the queries faster and render page in minimum amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

1. frist optimized the mysql query using joins and relationship
2. for user point of view , devide all the sections is block like recent
   activity is 1 block , photos 2nd block n bla bla bla
3. use ajax for loading the respective data , before load data show loading image.
4. use css and js in minified mode
5. do functional and oops approch
6. gtmatrix is online tool which will give you some hints for your project. gtmetrix.com

Comment: In addition to 1. Add proper indices to your tables after checking what exactly you are querying for.